# Many-to-Many relationship query using entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to do this query, using the Entity Framework:

```
SELECT uir.roleid
FROM UsersInRoles uir
WHERE uir.userid = @userid
```

UsersInRoles contains: `roleid` and `userid` only.

The problem is, `UsersInRoles` is a many-to-many relationship table. It connects my `Roles` and `Users` tables based on their PKs. The Entity Framework treats this very strangely by removing the UsersInRoles entity, and I'm having trouble understanding how to form the query.

This is what I have, but it's returning 27 rows when it should be returning only 2.

```
 var user_roles = admin_db.Roles
                    .Where(u => u.User.userid == db_userid)
                    .Select(r => r.roleid).ToList();
```

To tell the truth, I honestly can't even figure out how it's returning 27. That number of results makes no sense.

Comment: Your query looks like you have a `User` *reference* in `Role` and not a `Users` *collection*. Why is that? For a many-to-many relationship you should have a collection (a role can have *many* users and not only one).

Comment: @Slauma That is the problem I'm having. I don't understand how I should query based on the `Users` collection, restricting it to only return the roles each user has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Any` to find all roles that have *any* (at least one) user with the given user id:

```
var user_roles = admin_db.Roles
    .Where(r => r.Users.Any(u => u.userid == db_userid))
    .Select(r => r.roleid)
    .ToList();
```

Or - if you have a `Roles` collection in `User`:

```
var user_roles = admin_db.Users
    .Where(u => u.userid == db_userid)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.roleid))
    .ToList();
```